# Какова структура папок настоящего "боевого" веб проекта?

Tags: php, javascript, веб-программирование, frontend

Всем привет.
Суть: я занимаюсь фронтэндом. Использую Gulp и из-за этого у проекта получается такая структура:

[image: структура моего сайта]

В `/source/` все исходники, а в `/build/` всё что скомпилировал `Gulp`.

Как мне теперь прикрутить к этому бэкэнд? Все варианты к которым я пришёл сводятся к тому, чтобы просто скопировать содержимое папки `build` в другую папку и там уже начать заниматься бэкэндом.

Хотелось бы услышать мнение более опытных товарищей.

P.S. Может я вообще все неправильно делаю с самого начала?

P.S.S. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: а что "это" у вас и почему к нему нужно прикручивать бэкенд? В Gulp можно настроить нужную папку, куда будет ложиться итоговый результат выполнения скрипта.

Answer (score 2):

Структура папок уже определяется самим backend. У меня на проекте, все держится в папке ../../frontend, а собирается в папку target. Когда начнете прикручивать backend, структура папок и таски в галпе по несколько раз могут измениться.

Answer (score 2):

Backend — понятие растяжимое. Если бэкэнд на том же ноде, то тут можно организовать всё в одной папке (лучше всего, дабы не плодить node_modules). Если имеется в виду php, то результат сборки (папку build) можно вынести во вне в вашем gulpfile, и там уже строить бэкэнд.